# OpsHub VS Migration tool installer will not run in Windows 7

Tags: opshub

I tried running the installer numerous times, but could not get the utility to work. Nothing ever got created in `C:\Program Files\OpsHub\`.

I get prompted right away with the Windows 7 dialog:

> did this application get installed correctly? Yes it did or not try again with correct settings.

Once I try and re-run again using the correct settings selection nothing happens and the installer will not longer run at all.

Answer (score 0):

The Utility installs itself at *C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility*.

Can you verify if that directory is being created? What about Desktop icons and Start Menu shortcuts?

Also a point to note would be that the utility needs .NET Framework installed. Does you machine meet the System Requirements of the utility?